# Setting relative layout parameters

Tags: android, image, layout

So I'm trying to add an imageview to my current xml design - and its working decently. Now my main problem is that I cant seem to find a way to set the attributes for the image like where it needs to be displayed etc.

```
RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.board);

ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
i.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_1);
i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
mRelativeLayout.addView(i);
setContentView(mRelativeLayout);
```

I tried messing around with setlayoutparams but got absolutely no clue what to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have to use the class LayoutParams to do that efficiently and easily :

```
RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.board);
ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(40, 40);
params.leftMargin = 25;
params.topMargin = 25;
i.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
mRelativeLayout.addView(i, params);
```

This works for me and put my icon in the top left corner of the screen with the specified margin to the sides of the screen.
Does that help?

Comment: awesome, i had set my ieye on it, but couldnt understand the documentations.

Comment: You're lucky because I was just like you and understood it this morning. SO I was happy to share my understanding

Comment: what about stuff such as alignLeft etc? cannot seem to get it to recognise it, also it seems that all my pictures that was in the relativelayout to a start will ge tthe params from the last line.

Comment: ah found it :)

now its just how to make it a little more pretty.